# imacro purge facebook wall

Tags: facebook, firefox-addon, imacros

I have been working on an imacro script to loop through my facebook wall and purge all of my older posts.  so far I can get it to delete posts, however, I can not find a way to skip over images or posts that were published via techcrunch for example.  the kind where you can only hide them versus remove completely.

anyone have an experience in using imacros?

```
VERSION BUILD=7401110 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
WAIT SECONDS=5
URL GOTO=https://www.facebook.com/chrishough
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=8 TYPE=I ATTR=CLASS:mrs<SP>img<SP>sp_3jmqkp<SP>sx_d07d6f&&TXT:
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:itemLabel<SP>fsm&&TXT:Delete<SP>Post...
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=NAME:ok&&VALUE:Delete<SP>Post
WAIT SECONDS=5
REFRESH
```

Answer (score 0):

general solution would be scraping "from" name of each post and compare it using [eval](http://wiki.imacros.net/EVAL)